# Is gopkg.in/mgo.v2 compatible with mongo 3.6?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm using gopkg.in/mgo.v2 for mongodb queries using GOLang. 
Earlier, Mongodb version was 3.0 and now I'm planning to upgrade it to 3.6.
Are they compatible with each other?

Comment: I think mgo is supporting [3.6](https://github.com/globalsign/mgo/labels/3.6%20feature). But I'm not sure since I don't use mgo for mongoDB driver. I'm using [mongo-go-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) and it is compatible with 3.6.

Comment: It should be compatible with the old features of MongoDB 3.6 for sure, since MongoDB 3.6 ought to be backward compatible with 3.0. Whether it supports (or you need) new 3.6 features is another question.

Comment: Why are you still using this driver? [The MongoDB driver for Go. UNMAINTAINED](https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo), [go-mgo/mgo now unmaintained](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mgo-users/xQxKbDnxPIA/hU2J4g4AAwAJ) and [Considering the Community Effects of Introducing an Official MongoDB Go Driver](https://engineering.mongodb.com/post/considering-the-community-effects-of-introducing-an-official-golang-mongodb-driver)

Comment: There is a maintained version of gopkg by globalsign. You can include it by doing a: go get github.com/globalsign/mgo and go get github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson. There is a bit of work involved in swapping over the the official MongoDB driver, but it will be worth it in the end.